# dashes for same author name in bib file

Tags: bibtex

There are many questions (with answers) on how to fix the appearance of `-----` for the same author names in bibtex. However still I have problem!!

My bib file contains

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:nodash,
 CTLdash_repeated_names = "no",
}
@inproceedings{Ebrahimi09,
  author = {E. Ebrahimi and others},
  title = {Coordinated control of multiple prefetchers in multi-core systems},
  booktitle = {MICRO-42},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {316-326},
}
@inproceedings{Ebrahimi09_2,
  author = {E. Ebrahimi and others},
  title = {Techniques for bandwidth-efficient prefetching of linked data structures in hybrid prefetching systems},
  booktitle = {HPCA-15},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {7-17},
}
```

However the output file looks like

[image]

In fact changing `CTLdash_repeated_names = "no",` to `CTLdash_repeated_names = "yes",` has no effect! How can I fix that?

In the .tex file, the bibliography is called in this way

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\section{Introduction}
 ... works~\cite{Ebrahimi09,Ebrahimi09_2}
\bstctlcite{bstctl:etal, bstctl:nodash, bstctl:simpurl}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

I have a [script](http://nimal.info/blog/2010/latex-on-windows-with-miktex-and-notepad/) (in windows) that runs the following commands

```
:: Run pdflatex -&gt; bibtex -&gt; pdflatex -&gt; pdflatex
pdflatex %2  --file-line-error-style
bibtex  %2
:: If you are using multibib the following will run bibtex on all aux files
:: FOR /R . %%G IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %%G
pdflatex %2  --file-line-error-style
pdflatex %2
```

Comment: Did you run BibTeX then LaTeX again after changing the control value? You know that the IEEE style is specifically for submission to journals, and it _should not_ be messed about with, I assume.

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example? I wonder if you are correctly citing the control stuff.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the style.  If you change the entries to type `@article` instead of `@inproceedings` then it works as expected.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: No effect. I checked the blg file and found `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "bstctl:nodash"` What does that mean?

Comment: It means that it looked for and did not find that entry.  Does the log say it loaded the correct file?

Comment: Which file do you mean? bib? bst?

Answer (score 2):

Adding

@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:nodash,
CTLdash_repeated_names = "no",
}

at the begining of my .bib file worked for me. I am using IEEE transaction format.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `\bstctlcite` must be the first citation command. It will not work if there were any other `\cite`s issued before calling `\bstctlcite`.

The [IEEETran BibTeX style documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) explains

> `\bstctlcite` is  silent  —  it  will  not  add  any  entry  to,  or affect  the  numbering  of,  the  bibliography,  nor  will  it  place any  citation  numbers  in  the  main  text.   There  are  two  main limitations on its use:
>
> 1. For the unsorted BibTeX style, it must be placed before any  entries  that  it  is  to  affect.  Because  the  user  will almost  always  want  to  apply  the  changes  to  all  the bibliography  entries,  a  good  location  is  just  after `\begin{document}`.  For  the  sorting  style,  control  entries will  automatically  be  given  a  sort  key  value  that  will put  them  at  the  beginning  of  the  references.  If  this  is not  desired,  a  control  entry  can  be  manually  given  a `key` field with a value that will result in the desired sort position.
> 2. operation is “one shot.” That is to say the same control entry  cannot  be used  again  (within  the same  bibliography). However, it is possible to call another control entry that uses a different key name. This behavior is directly related to the way BibTeX allows a reference to be cited multiple times, yet still produces only one entry within the bibliography.

Hence

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:nodash,
 CTLdash_repeated_names = "no",
}
@inproceedings{Ebrahimi09,
  author = {E. Ebrahimi and others},
  title = {Coordinated control of multiple prefetchers in multi-core systems},
  booktitle = {MICRO-42},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {316-326},
}
@inproceedings{Ebrahimi09_2,
  author = {E. Ebrahimi and others},
  title = {Techniques for bandwidth-efficient prefetching of linked data structures in hybrid prefetching systems},
  booktitle = {HPCA-15},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {7-17},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{bstctl:etal, bstctl:nodash, bstctl:simpurl}

\section{Introduction}
 ... works~\cite{Ebrahimi09,Ebrahimi09_2}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

works as expected

[image: No dash in the bibliography.]

Answer (score -1):

If someone is not using the IEEEtran template but have the same trouble, in the `.bib` file just add at the beginning

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{bstctl:nodash,
 CTLdash_repeated_names = "no",
}
```

Then, in the `.tex` file, add the package `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}`. Finally, after the `\begin{document}` the next line must be `\bstctlcite{bstctl:nodash}`

Example:

```
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
<br>% ...
<br>\begin{document}
<br>\bstctlcite{bstctl:nodash}
<br> %your file content
<br> %your file content
```